# Vue3 and Vite: Codegen node is missing for element/if/for node. Apply appropriate transforms first

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, vitest

I creating a storybook app with components on based Quasar. While writing the tests, I got a problem with the slots (Vite).
It is component's code:

```
<template>
  <slot name="header" />
  <q-banner
    class="banner banner-border"
    v-bind="props"
  >
    {{ label }}
    <slot name="action" />
    <slot name="avatar" />
    <slot />
  </q-banner>
  <slot name="footer" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { QBannerProps } from 'quasar';

interface NovoBannerProps extends QBannerProps {
  class: string;
  label?: string;
}

const props = defineProps<NovoBannerProps>();
</script>
```

IT is test's code:

```
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/vue3';
import { StatusClass } from '@/models/enums/status.enum';
import { AppMoleculeBanner } from '../../../components';
import { AppBaseIcon } from '../../../components';

const meta: Meta<typeof AppMoleculeBanner> = {
  title: 'Molecules/Banner',
  component: AppMoleculeBanner,
  tags: ['autodocs'],
};

export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<typeof AppMoleculeBanner>;

const Default: Story = {
  render: (args) => ({
    components: { AppMoleculeBanner, AppBaseIcon },
    setup() {
      return { args };
    },
    template: `
      <app-molecule-banner v-bind="args">
        <template #avatar>
          <app-base-icon :color="args.color" :name="args.name" />
        </template>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
      </app-molecule-banner>
    `,
  }),
};

export const Primary = {
  ...Default,
  args: {
    class: StatusClass.PRIMARY,
    color: 'primary',
    name: 'error',
  },
};
```

And it is my error:

**Error: Codegen node is missing for element/if/for node. Apply appropriate transforms first.**

How could this problem be fixed?

Thank you in advance!